# How to format grafana Alert on teams via webhooks

Tags: azure, logging, grafana, microsoft-teams

when the alert is sent to my team’s channel, the pipeline name is truncated [see image below]

[alert on teams triggerd on grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H31zD.png)

I would like to know if there is anything I can do to make the entire variable name appear
I’m using grafana v7.5 and my data comes from Azure logs

```
{
  "firing": true,
  "state": "pending",
  "conditionEvals": "true = true",
  "timeMs": "430.287ms",
  "matches": [
    {
      "metric": "n {PipelineName=PPLCRGLOADORLTOAPOSENTEVT}",
      "value": 11
    }
  ],
  "logs": [
    {
      "message": "Condition[0]: Query",
      "data": {
        "from":number,
        "queries": [
          {
            "refId": "A",
            "model": {
              "appInsights": {
                "dimension": [],
                "metricName": "select",
                "timeGrain": "auto"
              },
              "azureLogAnalytics": {
                "query": "ADFActivityRun\r\n| where (Status == 'Failed') and (substring(ResourceId,135,3) == 'PRD') and TimeGenerated > ago(8h)\r\n| summarize n=count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 5min),PipelineName\r\n\r\n| project n,TimeGenerated,PipelineName",
                "resultFormat": "time_series",
                "workspace": "workspace"
              },
              "azureMonitor": {
                "aggOptions": [],
                "dimensionFilter": "*",
                "dimensionFilters": [],
                "metricDefinition": "select",
                "metricName": "select",
                "metricNamespace": "select",
                "resourceGroup": "select",
                "resourceName": "select",
                "timeGrain": "auto",
                "timeGrains": [],
                "top": "10"
              },
              "insightsAnalytics": {
                "query": "",
                "resultFormat": "time_series"
              },
              "queryType": "Azure Log Analytics",
              "refId": "A",
              "subscription": "subscription"
            },
            "datasource": {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "LA-DATAANALYTICS-PRD"
            },
            "maxDataPoints": 0,
            "intervalMs": 0
          }
        ],
        "to": #number
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "Condition[0]: Query Result",
      "data": {
        "fromDataframe": true,
        "series": [
          {
            "name": "n {PipelineName=PPLCRGLOADORLTOAPOSENTEVT}",
            "points": [
              [
                1,
                1628064600000
              ],
              [
                1,
                1628064900000
              ],
              [
                1,
                1628065200000
              ],
              [
                1,
                1628065500000
              ],
              [
                1,
                1628065800000
              ],
              [
                1,
                1628066100000
              ],
              [
                1,
                1628066700000
              ],
              [
                1,
                1628067000000
              ],
              [
                1,
                1628067300000
              ],
              [
                1,
                1628067600000
              ],
              [
                2,
                1628067900000
              ]
            ],
            "tags": {
              "PipelineName": "PPLCRGLOADORLTOAPOSENTEVT"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "Condition[0]: Eval: true, Metric: n {PipelineName=PPLCRGLOADORLTOAPOSENTEVT}, Value: 11.000",
      "data": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the JSON generated by test rule

And the length of pipeline name is something like 25 chars
(PPLCRGLOADORLTOAPOSENTEVT)

Comment: Can you share the JSON payload of the Adaptive Card? It will help us reproduce at our end. Also, please share the length of pipeline name.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT here it's i think

Comment: Is it a third party app or custom app you are building?

Comment: It is a dashboard of our company. All data comes from Azure logs (our too) and if any pipeline fails it will trigger a grafana alert that will send a message to our channel on microsoft teams

Comment: Hello, I am not sure if you have access to update the incoming message card, but I would suggest you to use Adaptive card because its *TextBlock* has *wrap* property. Here is the document for [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook).